# How do I conditionally execute code based on if a function is called or not?

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement

how can I do this:
in python, how can I do a loop or an if statment, that to get in the loop/ the if statment, you need a function to be called.
I mean something like this:

```
if function() *is called*:
  print('function() is called')
```

thanks

Comment: Does the function return anything?

Comment: The function is never called unless you call it. So where is the question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use booleans to handle that:

```
def function():
    function.has_been_called = True
    pass
function.has_been_called = False

#Actual Code!:
if function.has_been_called:
    print('function()is called')
```

The boolean will now store whether or not the fucntion has been called.

Comment: You calling the function here `function()`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that scama.

Answer (score 1):

Use a decorator to wrap the function, so that any time the function is called, you get a print, without having to alter your original function

```
def is_called(func):
  def wrap():
    func()
    print func, "is called"
  return wrap

@is_called
def function():
  pass

if function():
  pass #do
```

would print 'function is called'